# Angularjs nav active state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation

I have a navigation in Angularjs which have urls containing ids from a object
Now i want to make those navigation items set active if its match with the current location.

the template

```
<li ng-class="{active:isActive('/s/{{subject.id}}/popular')}"><a  href="#/s/{{subject.id}}/popular">POPULAR</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isActive('/s/{{subject.id}}/latest')}"><a  href="#/s/{{subject.id}}/latest">LATEST</a></li>
```

the controller

```
angular.module('pob.controllers', []).
  controller('appController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, APIservice){
    $scope.isActive = function(url) {
      console.log(url);
      if (url == $location.path()) {
      return true;
    }
      return false;
  };
}.controller('subjectController', function($scope, $routeParams, APIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.page = $routeParams.page;
    $scope.subject = [];
    $scope.votes = [];

    $scope.vote = function(vote, comment, id){
        console.log(vote);
        console.log(comment);
        console.log(id);
    };

    APIservice.getSubject($scope.id, $scope.page).success(function (response) {
        $scope.subject = response.subject;
         $scope.votes = response.votes;

    });

});
```

The problem is that "url" doesnt match with the location because of  console.log(url) returns "/s//popular".

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Where is `$scope.subject.id` defined?

Comment: In the subject controller

Comment: As long as `subject` contains an object that contains an `id` object this should work. I'd compare the actual url your browser presents to what angular spits out at you. `$loction.absUrl()` might be helpful in tracking down the issue.